# Displaying certain data that of a query D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have multiple CSV files that looks like this:

```
name,state,x,y
Anderson,VIC,34,765
Martin,VIC,55,345
James,NSW,46,129
Zoe,QLD,63,76
```

I'm using this data with a barchart, and have it loaded in so that all data is shown. I'm currently toying with the idea of when a user clicks a dropdown menu, only certain values will show. For example, if they click VIC, only data with a state of VIC will be shown. But I'm confused about how I can segregate the data like that? I thought my code below would work, but it doesn't:

```
svg.selectAll("mybar")
  .data(data, function(d) { return d.state["vic"];})
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); })
    .attr("fill", "blue")
```

The ideal output is that `return d.state["..."];` is updated depending on the state that has been selected in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have to add filter with data like.

```
data.filter(function(d){
            return d.category == category;
        })
```

AS

```
d3.select("body")
    .selectAll("div.h-bar")
    .data(data.filter(function(d){
        return d.category == category;
    }))
    .select("span")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.category;
    });
```

Here is the working example https://bl.ocks.org/fabiomainardi/00fd581dc5ba92d99eec