# Filtering data based on input D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to filter down data to one value based on input. If the user enters a value, I want it to be able to display only that value on the graph. However, it's not working. I believe the code is in all the right places, just the logic isn't there.

If I remove the functionallity that attempts this, everything is fine - meaning that if I click on A, only data with type A is returned, and the same with B. But this doesn't work when I implement my code that tries to fitler down to one value.

Question:

How can I filter down to one value along the x axis based on user input, but still retain the funcationality that allows the user to switch between data types.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input").attr("value", 0);
});

const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 65
  },
  width = 520,
  height = 480;

function SVGmaker(target) {
  const svg = d3.selectAll(target)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("fill", "white")

  return svg;
}

const svgOne = SVGmaker("#svg");

const data = [{
    x: "1",
    y: "5",
    type: "A"
  },
  {
    x: "2",
    y: "4",
    type: "B"
  },
  {
    x: "3",
    y: "3",
    type: "B"
  },
  {
    x: "4",
    y: "2",
    type: "A"
  },
  {
    x: "5",
    y: "1",
    type: "A"
  }
]

let x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, 5])
  .range([0, width]);

// DC SVG Settings
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

svgOne.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

const yAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 6])
  .range([height, 0])
svgOne.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis));

const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["A", "B"])
  .range(["red", "blue"]);

function updateData(data, type, theSVG, xAxis, yAxis, colors, value) {

  // Filters through the data
  const changeData = data.filter(function(d) {
    if (type === "A") {
      return d.type === "A"
    } else if (type === "B") {
      return d.type === "B"
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });

  var min = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  });

  const gra = theSVG
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(changeData);

  gra.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .filter(function(d) {
      if (value <= min) {
        return d.x
      } else {
        return d.x >= value && d.x <= value
      }
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xAxis(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yAxis(d.y);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colors(d.type)
    })
    .merge(gra)
    .attr("r", 11)
    .filter(function(d) {
      if (value <= min) {
        return d.x
      } else {
        return d.x >= value && d.x <= value
      }
    })
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xAxis(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yAxis(d.y);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colors(d.type)
    })

  gra.exit()
    .remove();

}

updateData(data, "", svgOne, x, yAxis, colors, 0);

let value;

function getMessage() {
  value = document.getElementById("#input").value;
}

d3.select("#a")
  .on("click", function() {
    updateData(data, "A", svgOne, x, yAxis, colors, value);
  });

d3.select("#b")
  .on("click", function() {
    updateData(data, "B", svgOne, x, yAxis, colors, value);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>



<div id="svg"></div>
<button id="a">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<input type="number" id="input" value=0>
<button id="submit">submit</button>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56291849/displaying-certain-data-that-of-a-query-d3/56291963#56291963

Comment: I did something similar. It's helpful, but just doens't help me precisely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit guessing what you want to do, but really the problem was that you never set'value' variable, and thus you were always passing undefined.

When you call getElementById, do not include the `#`.

Generally if you're not generating the tag/element with d3 or js, I'd personally attach the click listener with `onclick` attribute straight inside html instead of d3.on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#input").attr("value", 0);
});

const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 70,
    left: 65
  },
  width = 520,
  height = 480;

function SVGmaker(target) {
  const svg = d3.selectAll(target)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("fill", "white")

  return svg;
}

const svgOne = SVGmaker("#svg");

const data = [{
    x: "1",
    y: "5",
    type: "A"
  },
  {
    x: "2",
    y: "4",
    type: "B"
  },
  {
    x: "3",
    y: "3",
    type: "B"
  },
  {
    x: "4",
    y: "2",
    type: "A"
  },
  {
    x: "5",
    y: "1",
    type: "A"
  }
]

let x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, 5])
  .range([0, width]);

// DC SVG Settings
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

svgOne.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

const yAxis = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 6])
  .range([height, 0])
svgOne.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis));

const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["A", "B"])
  .range(["red", "blue"]);

function updateData(data, type, theSVG, xAxis, yAxis, colors, value) {

  // Filters through the data


  var min = d3.min(data, function(d) {
    return d.x;
  });

  const changeData = data
    .filter(function(d) {
      if (value >= min) {
        return d.x == value;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    })
    .filter(function(d) {
      if (type === "A") {
        return d.type === "A"
      } else if (type === "B") {
        return d.type === "B"
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  const gra = theSVG
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(changeData);

  gra.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 11)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colors(d.type)
    })
    .merge(gra)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xAxis(d.x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yAxis(d.y);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colors(d.type)
    })

  gra.exit()
    .remove();

}

updateData(data, "", svgOne, x, yAxis, colors, 0);

d3.select("#submit")
  .on("click", function() {
    var value = document.getElementById("input").value;
    updateData(data, "", svgOne, x, yAxis, colors, value);
   });

d3.select("#a")
  .on("click", function() {
    updateData(data, "A", svgOne, x, yAxis, colors, 0);
  });

d3.select("#b")
  .on("click", function() {
    updateData(data, "B", svgOne, x, yAxis, colors, 0);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>



<div id="svg"></div>
<button id="a">a</button>
<button id="b">b</button>
<input type="number" id="input" value=0>
<button id="submit">submit</button>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```